# MSIX -> Local Activation permission for COM server

Tags: com, dcom, msix

My package is installed in sideloaded way and keeps encountering the app-specific permission error.

Yes many suggest to alter permissions and owners manully in regedit and Component Services.

**My app is actually missing in the DCOM Config under the Component Services (DCOMCNFG, DCOMCNFG -32).**

I see neither errors in the proc monitor nor warnings. How can I grant permissions in this case and why isn't this specific task accomplished by the MSIX installer ?

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 

{2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54}

 and APPID 

{15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402}

 to the user PRECISION\Tommy SID (S-1-5-21-3771326467-2290839719-591499861-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

I attmepted to grant DCOM permission by using this PS modul but to no avail:

[Grant, Revoke, Get DCOM permissions using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Grant-Revoke-Get-DCOM-22da5b96?redir=0)

```
Import-Module .\DCOMPermissions

Grant-DCOMPermission -ApplicationID "{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}" -Account "SYSTEM" -Type Launch -Permissions LocalLaunch,LocalActivation -OverrideConfigurationPermissions
```

Keep witnessing the error in the Event Viewer and this prohibits my app to start up:

[Event Viewer exhibiting the error ID 10010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGad4.png)

I build the MSIX package with the help of this AppxManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10">
  <Identity Name="WeatherHistory" Version="0.7.0.2" Publisher="CN=Contoso Software, O=Contoso Corporation, C=US" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Weather History</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Cosmic ray</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Images/satelite.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18363.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18363.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="Weather.History" Executable="Weather.History.Splash.exe" EntryPoint="Weather.History.Splash">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="Weather History" Description="Frontend" Square150x150Logo="Images/satelite.png" Square44x44Logo="Images/satelite.png" BackgroundColor="yellow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" />
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Weather.History.Stylet.exe" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10" />
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="runFullTrust" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

... and addded code to my package entry point exe as

```
private async void LaunchProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
            {
                await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Exit($"Your Windows version is not supported.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Exit("Failed to launch Weather History", e);
        }
    }
```

There is a WPF splash attempts to launch another WPF both are based on the common TFM .NET 4.7. The first WPF ought to launch the second as a trusted process harnessing this MSIX package extension infrastructure. Pro boostrapper mechanism. If my take on is right.

This ain't a pacage bundle, so what architecture is my package actually targeting ? I always compile **Any CPU.**

I finally build the package by invoking the respective tool as :

```
makeappx.exe pack /v /o /f mapping.map /m Appxmanifest.xml /p ./Weather.History.msix
```

Answer (score 2):

[The EntryPoint indeed must be designated as trusted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyRVr.png)

```
EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication"
```